# Remove border of the div element when the device screen is small

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div elements side by side with a border as a separator. when it is viewed through mobile screen, I am aligning div elements to be on top of each other with bootstrap3. But I still see the border line as I am setting it in css. Can anyone help me out in removing the border with bootstrap and not with media queries??

Code:

```
.div-box{
        .make-row();
        .div-container{
            .make-sm-column( 6 );
        }
    }
    .div-container {
        float: left;
        padding-left:25px;
        border-left: 1px solid #aaaaaa;

    }
```

Comment: would be great if you can share the relevant code.

Comment: You need to use media queries

Comment: code added.. pls help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CSS media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .div-container {
    border: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries (Tambo answer) would be the best option, but if you do not want to use media queries you can use jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var elem = $('#elem');
    if (w < 480) {
        elem.css('border-left': 'none');
    } else {
        elem.removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```